# How to make a wordpress site a subdirectory in nginx?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a wordpress site located in `/var/www/example.com/sites/public`. I want this wordpress site to be accessed through `example.com/_api`. How can I do this? Here is the config I have at this moment:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name example.com;
            root /var/www/example.com/site/public;
            location /_api/ {
                    index index.php;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }
    }
```

I get 403 if I access `example.com`, which makes sense as there is no index file for root. But if I go to `example.com/_api` or `example.com/_api/index.php`, I get 404 error. What is the problem in this config? In what directory does nginx search in this config that `index.php` is not found?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't install WordPress to the `/_api/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a proxy_pass directive. Something like this

```
location /_api/ {
  proxy_pass http://www.example.com/whatever
}
```

Alternate you could just move Wordpress to the _api directory and then configure as follows

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
```

There's probably a dozen different ways to do this, someone may come up with a better one.